# Does LuaLaTeX mess with pagetotal?

Tags: luatex

MWE:

```
%%%! LuaLaTeX

\def\doSmth{\the\pagetotal\message{XXXXX::\the\pagetotal::XXXXX}}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Some text

Some text

Some text

\doSmth
\end{document}
% \bye
```

The macro `\doSmth` in this example writes the value of the `\pagetotal` register both onto the page and into the log. When I compile this example with LaTeX, plain TeX or luaTeX (last two with modifications for plain), both values — on the page and in the log — are equal, namely `34.0pt`. However when run with luaLaTeX the value on the page remains `34.0pt` but in the log I get `34.22pt`.

This difference seems small and insignificant (and who cares about some log anyway, right?), but it only demonstrates that something is wrong. The real problem is that in another (way more complex) case luaLaTeX treats `\pagetotal` as having zero value (and `\ifnum \pagetotal > 0` consequently fails), whilst at the same time printing its value on the page correctly (I temporarily put in a macro, right before that failing `\ifnum`, the same commands as in the `\doSmth` macro above and got on the page some `231.8pt` and zero in the log).

Using `LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.9.20)` on Linux. Any help appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:** After some more experimenting and testing it turns out that the problem is not that serious after all, or—to be precise—that this thing described here with different values and my problem with zero value were not related. Mine was actually my own bug caused by playing too freely with `\dimen0` in local contexts.

Comment: That's ... interesting, worth asking on luatex list I think (more chance of getting an authoritative answer there than here)

Comment: It looks like a timing problem. Try e.g. `\def\doSmth{\the\pagetotal\message{XXXXX::\the\pagetotal::XXXXX}\the\pagetotal}` and `\def\doSmth{\noindent\the\pagetotal\message{XXXXX::\the\pagetotal::XXXXX}}`

Comment: I can confirm both the behaviour described in the question as well as @UlrikeFischer's observation. Note that XeLaTeX has the same behaviour, printing `34.0pt` but logging `34.21999pt`.

Comment: Thank you all, I've found some more “interesting” stuff in the meantime so I'll just follow David's advice and write directly to luatex list.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see much difference from luatex and pdftex.

```
%% https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html
%%
%% everypar: holds tokens added at the beginning of every paragraph.
%%
%% pagetotal: is the accumulated height of the current page.
%%
\loggingall
\tracingpages=1000
\def\doSmth{\immediate\write12{>>before:t=\the\pagetotal .}\the\pagetotal\immediate\write12{>>after:t=\the\pagetotal .}}%
\everypar{\noindent\immediate\write12{>>everypar:t=\the\pagetotal}}%
\def\TESTCHAR{S}%
\def\TESTCHAR{m}%
\def\TESTCHAR{e}%
\def\TESTCHAR{\strut}%
\TESTCHAR%
\par%
\doSmth%
\def\TESTCHAR{S}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{o}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{m}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{e}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{\ }\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{t}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{e}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{x}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{t}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\def\TESTCHAR{\strut}\setbox0\hbox{\TESTCHAR}\immediate\write12{>>\TESTCHAR: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0 .}%
\bye
```

luatex with luatex-plain:

```
$>mtxrun --script plain test.tex|grep '>>' ;pdftotext test.pdf -;pdffonts test.pdf;
```

gives

```
>>before:t=10.0pt.
>>everypar:t=13.5pt
>>after:t=13.5pt.
>>S: wd=5.56pt, ht=7.05pt, dp=0.22pt.
>>o: wd=5.0pt, ht=4.48pt, dp=0.11pt.
>>m: wd=8.33pt, ht=4.42pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>e: wd=4.44pt, ht=4.48pt, dp=0.11pt.
>>\ : wd=3.33pt, ht=0.0pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.89pt, ht=6.15pt, dp=0.11pt.
>>e: wd=4.44pt, ht=4.48pt, dp=0.11pt.
>>x: wd=5.28pt, ht=4.31pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.89pt, ht=6.15pt, dp=0.11pt.
>>\relax \unhcopy \strutbox : wd=0.0pt, ht=8.5pt, dp=3.5pt.
10.0pt

1


name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JOCVHR+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
```

luatex with plain:

```
$> luatex test.tex|grep '>>';pdftotext test.pdf -;pdffonts test.pdf;
```

gives

```
>>everypar:t=0.0pt
>>before:t=10.0pt.
>>everypar:t=13.5pt
>>after:t=13.5pt.
>>S: wd=5.55557pt, ht=6.83331pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>o: wd=5.00002pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>m: wd=8.33336pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>e: wd=4.44444pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>\ : wd=3.33333pt, ht=0.0pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.8889pt, ht=6.15079pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>e: wd=4.44444pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>x: wd=5.2778pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.8889pt, ht=6.15079pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>\relax \unhcopy \strutbox : wd=0.0pt, ht=8.5pt, dp=3.5pt.
10.0pt

1


name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DLDTEG+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
```

and  pdftex

```
$>pdftex test.tex|grep '>>';pdftotext test.pdf -;pdffonts test.pdf
```

gives

```
>>everypar:t=0.0pt
>>before:t=10.0pt.
>>everypar:t=13.5pt
>>after:t=13.5pt.
>>S: wd=5.55557pt, ht=6.83331pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>o: wd=5.00002pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>m: wd=8.33336pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>e: wd=4.44444pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>\ : wd=3.33333pt, ht=0.0pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.8889pt, ht=6.15079pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>e: wd=4.44444pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>x: wd=5.2778pt, ht=4.30554pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>t: wd=3.8889pt, ht=6.15079pt, dp=0.0pt.
>>\relax \unhcopy \strutbox : wd=0.0pt, ht=8.5pt, dp=3.5pt.
10.0pt

1


name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DLDTEG+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
```

The log have more info, but practically when we typeset something several things happen not all in sync. 
Of course, all depends on the font used: the `'S'` of LMRoman10-Regular looks similar to the `'S'` of CMR10, but width, height an depth are not the same --- and the depth influences the `\pagetotal`. In this case using `\strut` gives the same result because `\strut` has the same dimensions in LMRoman10-Regular and CMR10; but already in LMRoman10-Regular the `'S'` and the `'o'` have different depths, and in CMR10 the depth of both is  `0pt`.

If we see the log, when TeX has to typeset the value of `\pagetotal`
which is `'10.0pt'` one consequence is the update  of `\pagetotal`
by the page builder
with the depth of `\strut`, which is `3.5pt` in this case for both the fonts (`\parskip` is `0.0pt plus 1.0pt`).
This is the new value of `\pagetotal` seen by `\message`:

```
\doSmth ->\immediate \write 12{>>before:t=\the \pagetotal .}\the \pagetotal \im
mediate \write 12{>>after:t=\the \pagetotal .}
{vertical mode: \immediate}
\write->>>before:t=\the \pagetotal .
>>before:t=10.0pt.
{\the}
{the character 1}
\everypar->\noindent \immediate \write 12{>>everypar:t=\the \pagetotal }
% t=10.0 g=643.20255 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
{horizontal mode: \noindent}
{\immediate}
\write->>>everypar:t=\the \pagetotal 
>>everypar:t=13.5pt
{the character 1}
{the character 0}
{the character .}
{the character 0}
{the character p}
{the character t}
{\immediate}
\write->>>after:t=\the \pagetotal .
>>after:t=13.5pt.
```

With  `\def\TESTCHAR{S}` instead of `\def\TESTCHAR{\strut}` we have another value of depth, and in this case the fonts differ by  `0.22pt`;
and with `\def\TESTCHAR{m}` both the fonts agree between them as also with the value in the pdf (`10pt`).